# hide second modal if condition is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 modal and I check validation of form of first modal and if entries of textboxes were empty .second modal should not be shown.I cannot do this. user is id of my first modal and permission is id of my second modal.
java script code:

```
function valid() {
    var bool = true;

    var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (!pt.test(email)) {

        bool = false;
    }

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (name.length < 1) {
        bool = false;
    }

    return bool;
}
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    var bool = valid();

    if (bool == false) {
        $('#permission').modal('hide');
    } else {
        $('#user').modal('hide');
        $('#permission').modal('show');
    }


});
```

my html code:

```
<form onsubmit="return valid()">
    <button role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#permission" id="btn1">set permission</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this in the valid() function?

```
function valid() {
    var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    return pt.test(email) && name.length>1;
}
```

Comment: I've also cleaned up the function a bit - you don't really need that bool variable if you're just doing a simple test like this. As an empty string will not pass the regex validation, there's no need to check the length of it.

Comment: @Sedir : thanks for reply ... but totally my problem is with showing the second one .    else {
        $('#user').modal('hide');
        $('#permission').modal('show');
    }    this part of my code doesnt work and I dont know what it the second modal problem with  validation????

Comment: Could you provide the full HTML and JS then please, and I'll try to answer your question again. Use jsfiddle or something like that to host the code.